# Drawing vectors in GE

Tags: api, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

for my project I need to draw a vector around the whole globe connecting 2 points. For example, I've created points and draw the line between them:

```
    vectorStringMark = ge.createPlacemark('');
    vectorString = ge.createLineString('');
    vectorStringMark.setGeometry(vectorString);
    vectorString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(vectorStart.getGeometry().getLatitude(), vectorStart.getGeometry().getLongitude(), 0);
    vectorString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(vectorEnd.getGeometry().getLatitude(), vectorEnd.getGeometry().getLongitude(), 0);

    vectorString.setTessellate(true);
    vectorString.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND);

    vectorStringMark.setStyleSelector(ge.createStyle(''));
    var vectorStyle = vectorStringMark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
    vectorStyle.setWidth(6);
    vectorStyle.getColor().set('aaffffaa');

    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(vectorStringMark);
```

so, this code creates the line between 2 points BUT always takes the nearest distance between them. If I draw another string and swap the points, I'll get the same line going back from endpoint to startpoint. What I need is this new line connecting 2 points around the globe and with the longest distance, so I get a 'belt' encircling Earth.
Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another point in the antipodes of one of the original point.
this webpages calculates the antipodes of a point
http://joehohk.0fees.net/Location.htm

Comment: The problem is I'm adding the point on 'click' mouse event, another click adds second point etc. So, my script adds points and draws lines between them automatically, and I can't just enter manual coords for new point.